# Is every JavaScript program also a TypeScript program?

Tags: javascript, typescript

[Typescript Language Specification](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) says:

> Every JavaScript program is also a TypeScript program

Now consider this code:

```
var i = 5;
i = "five";
```

This is a perfectly valid javascript that will execute with no error. It is NOT a valid TypeScript, and it will fail to compile.

There is clearly mismatch in my understanding of the quoted statement above and the code example.

Could you please clarify, what makes the spec statement true in the context of the example I gave above.

**Update**

To address the argument that the statement does not reflect a program validity, let's rephrase it this way:

> Every JavaScript program is also a valid or invalid TypeScript program

or

> Every JavaScript program is not necessarily a valid TypeScript program

If the authors wanted to say the latter, why did not they say that?

Comment: clearly the statement is flawed (or completely false, depends on your interpretation of truth)

Comment: I suppose that was equivalent to `var i: any = 5;` once and the statement wasn’t updated as the language was? (Or maybe I’m just misremembering.)

Comment: another way to look at it ... `Every JavaScript "program" is also a TypeScript "program"` but not necessarily a VALID TypeScript "program"

Comment: @JaromandaX that last interpretation does not make much sense in something as rigorous as a language spec is supposed to be.

Comment: @zespri - false statements make less sense. What is IN the spec is false and misleading. My second (tongue in cheek) comment is true and not at all misleading, so, if you have to choose between the two? (clearly, removing the statement altogether would be the best option)

Comment: So this so called specification apparently is a mess. [This quote](https://gist.github.com/AndrewSav/aeade21d416437a9f69a) is also false in the current version of VS2015.

Comment: @zespri it depends if it's a const enum or a regular enum. See this: http://goo.gl/R0GQLe I think the spec is missing that out, but I wouldn't consider that "a mess"

Comment: It still compiles with Typescript, it just gives you a warning that you are doing something wrong. Yes, that is wrong.

Comment: @DavidSherret, facinating! I wish I could upvote you twice!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems the question is being asked as if the statement read:

> Every JavaScript program is also a *semantically correct* TypeScript program

That statement would be false, but that's not what's being said here.

If you try to compile this *syntactically* correct TypeScript code...

```
var i = 5;
i = "five";
```

...you will get a compile error because it's not *semantically* correct—it's assigning a string to a variable implicitly typed as a number. However, since it's *syntactically* correct, the compiler will still output to the `.js` file with the same code above in addition to throwing the compile error.

So is every JavaScript program also a TypeScript program? Yes, but that doesn't mean you won't get compile errors.

Sidenote: You can stop the compiler from emitting on an error by specifying `--noEmitOnError` when compiling.

---

**Addressing Update**

What they could have done is expanded upon this by qualifying that:

> Every syntactically correct JavaScript program is also a syntactically correct TypeScript program.

However, when you look at the quote in its context you can see the main idea introduced at the start of the paragraph is already about the syntax:

> TypeScript is a syntactic sugar for JavaScript. TypeScript syntax is a superset of Ecmascript 5 (ES5) syntax. Every JavaScript program is also a TypeScript program.

And so, maybe the author thought saying "syntactically correct" would have been repetitious.

Comment: This makes sense. I did not realize that it still can emits the javascript even in presence of typescript error. I'll accept an answer in a couple of days, and so far, you are the winner =)

Comment: "You can remove the condition and arrive at the original statement" exactly my point.

Answer (score 6):

The phrase should be intended at the syntax level. The code

```
var i = 5;
i = "five";
```

is valid TypeScript **syntax**, but will generate a **compile** error because of the extra checks that TypeScript does.

Basically that part says that TypeScript is an extension and not a redesign of Javascript syntax (if this is a good thing or not really depends on your views, though).

Comment: Huh? This IS a syntax error in TypeScript. You do not imply that it's a semantic error (as opposed to syntax error), do you?

Comment: @zespri: it's not a **syntax** error. Basically the statement `i = "five";` is correct... it's an expression-statement where the expression is an assignment operator call with the left side being an identifier and the right side a literal. To decide if this is valid or not there are other checks that require symbol lookup... e.g. if the identifier is defined, if it's of the correct type and so on. This kind of check is not part of what is called the language **syntax**. You don't get a "syntax error", you get a "type error", for example.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. The only type of errors that a compiler can detect is syntax errors. Terms "compile-time error" and "syntax error" are interchangeable. Considering a single statement in isolation is meaningless, as a single statement is not a compilation unit in TypeScript or JavaScript.

Comment: @zespri: you can use any definition you like (a definition is never wrong, by definition ;-) ). However in mainstream compiling technology (tokenization/parsing/compilation) normally a line is drawn at when symbol lookup is needed: only what comes before that line is "syntax".

Comment: `The only type of errors that a compiler can detect is syntax errors` -- Demonstrably false.  Have a look at compilers for languages that practice strong typing.  Type errors are detected at compile time in such languages.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, I think I was wrong here. Basically what I said was based on [C++ for Engineers and Scientists By Gary Bronson](http://www.amazon.com/Engineers-Scientists-Gary-J-Bronson/dp/1133187846) that I came across recently, but pulling of the shelf second edition of Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools by [Alfred Aho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Aho), which I consider authoritative in the field I see that it does not agree with mister Bronson. So I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is perfectly valid TypeScript. If this was the code in a TypeScript application it would still generate a JavaScript file for you. You can remove the warning with:

```
var i: string|number = 5;
i = "five";
```

Of course, because you have some type information hanging around, TypeScript can warn you about *potential* mistakes. In return, you can improve the type information it uses as I have above to explain how you intend to use a variable.

We now have an application that allows the original code, where `i` is a string or a number, but will prevent a later accident where someone tries to assign something else.

Comment: VS2015 generates *error* not a *warning*. Warning I would understand.

Comment: Until teams treat warnings more seriously, it is probably best it is an error. If this was a genuine mistake, rather than intentional code, imagine the time lost investigating the bug.